# Filling non-numeric values in Pandas based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have missing non-numeric data in a pandas dataframe, is there a way of replacing the NaN with the value from a different row when another column matches? E.g:

```
tdf = pandas.DataFrame({
    "id": [np.nan, 22, 22, 45, 45, 81],
    "item": ["apple", "apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", "banana"]
})

    id  item
0   NaN apple
1   22  apple
2   22  apple
3   45  orange
4   45  orange
5   81  banana
```

So I would want to replace the id in the first row with 22 because the item is the same as row 1 or 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on 'item' and pass param `as_index=False` and then call `bfill` to fill the `NaN` values backwards:

```
In [424]:

tdf.groupby('item', as_index=False)..bfill()
Out[424]:
   id    item
0  22   apple
1  22   apple
2  22   apple
3  45  orange
4  45  orange
5  81  banana
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for but didn't come across this possibility yet.